# Can't see Access control (IAM) under Subscriptions

Tags: azure, azureportal

I want to give an account access to an Azure account but I can't see "Access control (IAM)" in the subscriptions area. Why might this be? Does it disappear when Active Directory is in use on the account?

Comment: Is it your own subscription? or you're added by someone?

Comment: I'm using the administrator account. So I should have total control.

Comment: Oh, I think the "global administrator" is a different account.

Comment: Under "Settings", please click on "My permissions". It should tell you what permissions you have on the Subscription. An Azure AD administrator does not necessarily mean a Subscription administrator.

Comment: I've answered the question .

Answer (score 1):

It should be simply enabled and possible to see the IAM under subscription. There are three things you could do it,

(i)  Check if you are the global administrator for the subscription

(ii) Check if you have multiple subscription, select the proper one you hold the administrator right

(ii) Open a ticket to the subscription and billing team. They should be able to help point us to what is blocking you and if anything possibly add that subscription for you.

Answer (score 0):

When there are multiple subscriptions, you need to click through to an individual subscription to see this setting.